# How to upload videos into custom object record

Tags: custom-field

How to upload videos into custom object record like as photo upload in rich text field. no need to display a link i want to display a video

Answer (score 9):

Salesforce doesn't really shine as a streaming video provider ;) so the best route for an admin is to integrate with a third party service like Youtube. They handle encoding, hosting, and the video player:

1. create a `YouTubeId__c` text field on your custom object to hold the youtube `?v=` id,
2. write a `WidgetVideoPlayer` Visualforce Page which embeds the content, for example:

   ```
   <apex:page standardController="Widget__c" showHeader="false">
     <apex:iframe height="240" src="https://www.youtube.com/v/{!Widget__c.YouTubeId__c}" />
   </apex:page>
   ```

Then you can edit the Page Layout for your Custom Object and place your Visualforce Page in a section alongside the other fields.

[image: embedded video player]

It will be taxing to get this functionality embedded in a rich text field. If you did store the videos on platform, you could write a [shortcode](http://doc.silverstripe.org/framework/en/reference/shortcodes) parser and use [JWPlayer](http://www.jwplayer.com/) to attempt to tighten the integration.

Comment: hi user320                                                 what datatype YouTubeId__c and what id to store YouTubeId__c field.

Comment: @user320 nice video must check that out! ;-)

Comment: thanks user320. its working fine. can i store this video in salesforce. no need to call external youtube website

Comment: Not easily, @user4812. How much time+resource do you have? Big videos could be uploaded as Chatter Files. It will live at  `/sfc/servlet.shepherd/version/download/068_version_id_here` which you might be able to feed to [JWPlayer](http://www.jwplayer.com/) but I don't recommend it.